# Error Rendering report with multiple parameters

Tags: vb.net, parameters, pdf-generation

I have a project I am trying to fix that was created by a person that no longer works with our company.  Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this

> LocalProcessingException Occurred

error?  Below is my code.  It dies on `Response.Buffer = True`.  All of my parameters have data in them.  But it seems as though one of the report generation variables doesn't have data in them.  I am assuming its one of these

- `warnings`
- `streamids`
- `mimeType`
- `encoding`
- `format`
- `extension`
- `devInfo`

Any help would be great.  I have tried a lot of the other suggestions on this site but to no avail.  And as I said this is really the first code I've gotten into.  The stack trace is at the end.

```vb
//report generation variables
Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
Dim mimeType As String = ""
Dim encoding As String = ""
Dim format As String = "PDF"
Dim extension As String = ""
Dim devInfo As String = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>True</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>"
Dim bytes As Byte() = Nothing
Dim lr As New LocalReport

Dim leadsTable As DataTable = retrievePersons(caseNum.Text)
Dim supplTable As DataTable = CType(Session("personTable"), DataTable)
Dim personTable As DataTable = combinePersons(leadsTable, supplTable)

//if there is data ...
If personTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

//assume the best ....
ctlNotice.Visible = False
ctlNotice.Text = ""

//retrieve the charges
Dim chargesTable As DataTable = retrieveCharges(caseNum.Text)
Dim chargesTable As DataTable = CType(Session("chargeTable"), DataTable)
Dim employeeTable As DataTable = retrieveEmployee()
Session("employeeTable") = employeeTable

//make sure there were charges added
If chargesTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    ctlNotice.Visible = True
    ctlNotice.Text = "There are no charges.  Please add them first."
Else
    lr.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CRForm.rdlc"
lr.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("ACRDataSet_DataTable1", personTable))

//charges for the charge subreport
lr.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Charges02_ChargesTable", chargesTable))

//employee specific information
lr.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Employee2", employeeTable))

//add the datasource update to the subreport
AddHandler lr.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf SubreportProcessingEventHandler
lr.SetParameters(myParam)
deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>"

Try
    bytes = lr.Render(format, devInfo, extension, encoding, mimeType, streamids, warnings)
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = mimeType
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ChargingRequest_" + cleanCaseNum(caseNum.Text) + ".pdf")
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
    Response.Flush()
    Session("localReport") = bytes
    Catch exn As Exception
    ctlNotice.Text = "Call Support!.  Can't create the report! " & exn.Message
    ctlNotice.Visible = True
End Try
```

---

## Stack Trace

```
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at ChargingRequest._Default.btnPrint_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in H:\Visual Studio 2010\ChargingRequest\ChargingRequest\ChargeReq.aspx.vb:line 301`
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a relatively ancient post, but it popped up on a related Google search for me. Was it a typo on "deviceInfo" into your Render method?

```
deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>"

Try
bytes = lr.Render(format, *devInfo*, extension, encoding, mimeType, streamids, warnings)
```

Should be:

```
deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>"

Try
bytes = lr.Render(format, *deviceInfo*, extension, encoding, mimeType, streamids, warnings)
```